# What is the largest Kickstarter image size that is not scaled down for all?

Tags: images, kickstarter

On the Kickstarter site they write:

> Your project image size should be 1024x768 pixels (4:3 ratio). We accept most major image formats, but for best results upload one of our recommended file types: JPEG, PNG, or BMP. The maximum image size is 50MB.

So does that mean no matter how many pixels my image is, it will be downsized to 1024x768?

If so, why accept up to 50MB files?

If not, what is the maximum pixel size that is not always downsized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the book titled **[Kickstarter for Online Sellers: Get the Money You Need to Fund Your New Product Line](https://books.google.ca/books?id=ZWd3CgAAQBAJ)** the author suggests that the images be ***at least*** 1024x768 pixels not a limit of that.